# Flutter calculate amount by foreach loop

Tags: flutter, dart

I have some data and i am simply printing it by forEach loop I need to calculate the price.

Here is simple code

```
allRows.forEach((row) => print(row));
```

It's printing its results like this

```
[        ] I/flutter (31845): {id: 1195, title: Fajita Pizza (S),color: Grey, price: 199.0, sizeselect: Small}
[   +1 ms] I/flutter (31845): {id: 1211, title: Tikka Pizza (M),color: Black, price: 349.0, sizeselect: Small}
```

What I need to do is I need to calculate or sum the price and print the values.

So expected output is `548`

Answer (score 0):

```dart
var amount = 0;
allRows.forEach((row) {
 amount += row.price;
 print(row);
});
```

Comment: `var amount = allRows.reduce((a, b) => a + b);`